# How to write json and use it in ionic 2/3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ionic2, ionic3

I want to write json such as this example and use it in my program

```
{
    "users":[{"name":"a","age":4},{"name":"b","age":7}],
    "items":[{"name":"item1","price":"$44.2"},{"name":"item2","price":"$12.5"}]
}
```

So, is my json is correct ?

if "yes", how can I put it in array to use it such as this code:

```
let users= //some thing that give me the data of users from the json
this.users.forEach(u=>{
  console.log(u.name+" "+u.age)
});
```

if my json is not correct, please try to help me!

**Note:**

my full json already uploaded on server and I used this code to get it

```
getJson(){
    let url="MY JSON URL";
    this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        // the data received without problem
        ...
        let users= //some thing that give me the data of users from the json
        users.forEach(u=>{
            console.log(u.name+" "+u.age)
        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: not exactly sure what's the problem here. you can check the validity of JSON yourself on https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: I wrote this question because I can't use the data from the json.. I checked must of solutions but nothing return the values of users.. so I don't know is the problem from json or code of extracr the array from the json

Comment: is your JSON referenced by some variable like `data` or anything else? you can use `data.users`

Comment: yes, check my last edit for question

Comment: you should be using `data.users.forEach` instead of `this.users`

Answer (score 0):

You should be reading the `users` from `data` instead of `this`. `this.users` is probably `undefined`. Check the code below

```
getJson(){
    let url="MY JSON URL";
    this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        // the data received without problem
        ...
        const { users } = data;
        users.forEach(user => {
            console.info(`${user.name} ${user.age}`);
        });
    });
 }
```